# Jquery slide and explode

Tags: jquery

I have this function wich slides an animation to the left, but my problem is that once the animation started, the "explode" function dosn't take any other parameters like  { pieces: 16 } what function should i use to make this work ?

And 1 more thing if i click and go to next page when  i press back both disapear what should i do to display them again ? Tnks a lot

```
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#slideleft").animate(
        {marginLeft:'300px'},'slow')}
            , 1000);    
    $("#slideleft").click(function() {
        $(this).hide("explode", { pieces: 16 }, 2000);
          $('#slideright').hide();
    });
```

Comment: What does `not take any other parameters` mean? Does explode work or not? I am confused about what is wrong. Perhaps a http://jsfiddle.net would help. Do you want it to slide, then explode? Or slide and explode at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"explode" needs margin-left to do it's work. You highjacked it with your animation. Using a container

```
<div id="container"><div id="slideleft"></div></div>
```

you can get all 16 pieces

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#container").animate(
        {marginLeft:'300px'},'slow')}
            , 1000);    
    $("#slideleft").click(function() {
        $(this).hide("explode", { pieces: 16 }, 2000);
          $('#slideright').hide();
    });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nEDvx/4/)

Comment: a bit off topic....but the jquery documentation sais you can also implode things....how is this done?